# How to implement notification app badge icon in flutter using FCM?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, badge

I have been using Firebase push notification , and it all works. I want to show notification in app launcher icon with its count. I have seen many examples regarding this but unfortunately i could not achieve it. 
  I have read to give badge permission. But where to give those permission and how? I have tried using the below package too

```
 flutter_app_badger: ^1.1.2
```

but failed. Can somebody find me a solution. 
It would be more helpful to get a solution regarding FCM badge permission.